# Why docker RUN command causes exec error anytime?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, docker-run

I installed docker on Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit system. 
Then in example DockerFile,  when i type RUN command  with anything,  i get error:

DockerFile:

```
RUN ls
```

Then i run build Docker command:

```
sudo docker build - < Dockerfile
```

And i receive at this line:

```
---> Running in 1685b032aefd
exec format error
INFO[0000] [8] System error: exec format error
```

So i want to move forward with this problem. 
I use 32 bit ubuntu, but installed docker with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989534/how-to-install-docker-on-32bit-machine-having-ubuntu-12-04) trick.

Also i run docker as root, so maybe that may be a reason?

How to properly execute RUN command in docker in my situation?  I prefer rather not to change OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error indicates you're trying to run binaries from another architecture. Most likely 64-bit binaries on a 32-bit host.