# Playwright installation Error. pip install playwright gives ''No matching distribution"

Tags: python, pip, playwright

When tried to install from `pip install playwright` as mentioned on the [pypi website](https://pypi.org/project/playwright/) I got the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement playwright (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for playwright
```

In [installation docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) it was mentioned to use `pip install pytest-playwright` . After using it, pip started downloading all the available versions (not the latest or just a single one) then gave error that the version dependencies conflict with each other. As a fix I am asked to remove version from the command line (which I never gave).

I am using linux 32bit, python 3.8 interpreter, pycharm venv

1. Is the `pip install playwright` not working because of 32 bit machine (however it is not mentioned anywhere, or maybe I didn't see).
2. What's wrong happening with `pip install pytest-playwright`

Please help.
Shell output with `pip install pytest-playwright` is here.

```
pip install pytest-playwright
Collecting pytest-playwright
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pytest
  Using cached pytest-7.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting pytest-base-url
  Using cached pytest_base_url-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.6 kB)
Collecting pytest-playwright
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.11-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (9.9 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached pytest_playwright-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
  Downloading pytest_playwright-0.0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
  Downloading pytest_playwright-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.1 kB)
  Downloading pytest_playwright-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
  Downloading pytest_playwright-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install pytest-playwright==0.0.10, pytest-playwright==0.0.11, pytest-playwright==0.0.12, pytest-playwright==0.0.2, pytest-playwright==0.0.3, pytest-playwright==0.0.4, pytest-playwright==0.0.4.1, pytest-playwright==0.0.5, pytest-playwright==0.0.6, pytest-playwright==0.0.7, pytest-playwright==0.0.8, pytest-playwright==0.0.9, pytest-playwright==0.1.0, pytest-playwright==0.1.1, pytest-playwright==0.1.2, pytest-playwright==0.2.0, pytest-playwright==0.2.1, pytest-playwright==0.2.2, pytest-playwright==0.2.3 and pytest-playwright==0.3.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    pytest-playwright 0.3.0 depends on playwright>=1.18
    pytest-playwright 0.2.3 depends on playwright>=1.13
    pytest-playwright 0.2.2 depends on playwright>=1.13
    pytest-playwright 0.2.1 depends on playwright>=1.13
    pytest-playwright 0.2.0 depends on playwright>=1.13
    pytest-playwright 0.1.2 depends on playwright>=1.10.0
    pytest-playwright 0.1.1 depends on playwright>=1.10.0
    pytest-playwright 0.1.0 depends on playwright>=1.10.0
    pytest-playwright 0.0.12 depends on playwright>=1.9.0
    pytest-playwright 0.0.11 depends on playwright==1.8.0a1
    pytest-playwright 0.0.10 depends on playwright>=0.170.0
    pytest-playwright 0.0.9 depends on playwright>=0.0.4
    pytest-playwright 0.0.8 depends on playwright>=0.0.4
    pytest-playwright 0.0.7 depends on playwright>=0.0.4
    pytest-playwright 0.0.6 depends on playwright>=0.0.4
    pytest-playwright 0.0.5 depends on playwright>=0.0.4
    pytest-playwright 0.0.4.1 depends on playwright==0.0.4
    pytest-playwright 0.0.4 depends on playwright
    pytest-playwright 0.0.3 depends on playwright
    pytest-playwright 0.0.2 depends on playwright

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can see the actual wheel list at the  "Download files" tab: https://pypi.org/project/playwright/1.25.2/#files
   There you will see that unfortunately no wheels were built for linux 32bit
2. `pytest-playwright` try to install  playwright but failes because it doesnt find any (same issue as the first)

Comment: Ok. Thanks, saw the files. So it will work with 32 bit only for Win machine. On Linux it needs 64 bit. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Is there a way to use playwright on Linux 32bit, like Docker (which officially is available only for 64bit) has been [made available for 32bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989534/how-to-install-docker-on-32bit-machine-having-ubuntu-12-04/48881019#48881019).